# I am trying to call a function called sendEmail() after getting a response from inserting data into mysql

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to call a function call sendEmail() after getting a response from inserting data into mysql. However it doesn't seem to work. I have tested the sendEmail() function on its own and it works but its only when I try to call it when the affectedRows === 1. Sorry if the solution is easy, I am not really good at coding.

```
function signup() {
    var response = "";
    var userinfo = new Object();

    userinfo.userName = document.getElementById("userName").value;
    userinfo.password = document.getElementById("password").value;
    userinfo.email = document.getElementById("email").value;    
    userinfo.birthDate = document.getElementById("birthDate").value;
    userinfo.phoneNo = document.getElementById("phoneNo").value;
    userinfo.townName = document.getElementById("townName").value;
    userinfo.street = document.getElementById("street").value;
    userinfo.blkNo = document.getElementById("blkNo").value;
    userinfo.unitNo = document.getElementById("unitNo").value;
    userinfo.verifyCode = randomVerify(9);

    useremail = userinfo.email;
    userverifycode = userinfo.verifyCode;
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

    request.open("POST", "/user", true);
    request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

    request.onload = function() {
        response = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
        if(response.affectedRows === 1){
        sendEmail(useremail, userverifycode);
        }

        else{
            alert("Sign Up failed");

        }
    };

  request.send(JSON.stringify(userinfo));
}
```

Also the data gets saved to my database in mysql so I assume the part that has the problem is around the request.onload part?

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work"? And does your `request.onload` handler get called?

Comment: the request.onload handler does get called, if I replace the sendEmail(useremail, userverifycode); with for example an alert it sends the alert. It just doesn't want to call functions.

Comment: Unless the `sendEmail` function is outside of the scope, it should definitely get called. What do you get when you `console.log(sendEmail)` inside of that handler?

Comment: what do you mean by outside of the scope? sorry I am still learning how coding works and the different phrases

Comment: There's a good read here - https://scotch.io/tutorials/understanding-scope-in-javascript, but what do you see when you `console.log(sendEmail)` inside the handler?